# Javascript runtime exception when reading Json Serialized values

Tags: javascript, c#, json, razor

I'm currently having difficulties converting a c# list of type strings into a Json object. My problem occurs when I'm reading this Json object at a later time in javascript. I'm doing this same process with a c# list of type ints and the syntax seems to be fine. Here is some code snippets:

Razor Serialization:

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.reject_count);
var label = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.messages);
```

Javascript:

```
 var data = @data;
 var ls = @labels;
```

Attached is an image of the dynamic debugger value:

[image]
I've also attempted to change my serializer settings. Here is the snippet:

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSerializer.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii;
var labels = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.messages, formatting: Formatting.Indented, settings: jsonSerializer);
```

Is there another option when serializing c# lists of strings into Json objects to be read at a later point in time in Javascript? Or is there something I can modify to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `var ls = @labels;` in razor then `labels` is encoded in HTML and every `"` is replaced by `&quot;` what breaks your javascript code.

If you want to have string output without any conversion use `@Html.Raw(...)`

```
 var data = @Html.Raw(data);
 var ls = @Html.Raw(labels);
```